# LLVM: How to Cross Compile C++ Programs

Tags: c++, llvm, cross-compiling, clang++, libstdc++

I tried to use LLVM to compile C++ source code to arm binaries. Here's an example:

```
//hello.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I use the following commands:

```
clang++ -emit-llvm -c hello.cpp -o hello.bc
llc -march=arm hello.bc -o hello.s // I do need this step for running some backend optimizations 
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -static hello.s -o hello.exe
```

There was no warnings or errors so far. Then I tried to run the "hello.exe" with qemu-arm and gem5 simulator, both crashed with segmentation fault:

output from qemu-arm:

```
qemu-arm hello.exe
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

output form gem5:

```
~/gem5/build/ARM/gem5.opt ~/gem5/configs/example/se.py -c ./hello.exe
**** REAL SIMULATION ****
info: Entering event queue @ 0.  Starting simulation...
panic: Page table fault when accessing virtual address 0xfffffff4
@ tick 2035000
[invoke:build/ARM/sim/faults.cc, line 70]
Memory Usage: 646432 KBytes
Program aborted at cycle 2035000
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I was using clang version 3.7.0svn. Am I missing anything? In fact the compiling process was used to several c programs and they all worked correctly. But not for c++ programs.

Comment: Do your build and execution environments have compatible C++ libraries?

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes it makes sense that the segmentation fault happens if the c++ libraries are not compatible. I was using precompiled arm cross compiler, I'm pretty sure it has its own c++ libs. But how to check whether it is compatible? Or can I use command line options to force the llvm backend to use certain c++ libs? Thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: Perhaps you should link using the linker that matches your compiler (i.e. link with `g++` only when you compile with `g++`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work in this way. In fact, LLVM IR is not target neutral, therefore compiling x86 IR to ARM won't work: ABIs are different, etc.

You need to use clang's -target option (or build clang as a cross-compiler specifying the default target).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm now reading the llvm documents on how to do cross compilation using -target options. BTW, I don't understand why does the above method has no problem on c program?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone's help. I just figured out how it would work:

```
clang++ -target arm-none-linux-gnueabi --sysroot=/usr/local/arm-2009q3 -static hello.cpp -emit-llvm -c -I /usr/local/arm-2009q3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include/
llc hello.bc
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -static hello.s -o hello.exe
```

The arm binary runs properly on both qemu-arm and gem5.

I thought the LLVM IR should be totally independent from the target machine but in fact it is not (weird...)

I'm still not understand why c programs didn't have this problem.

Comment: For C you simple were lucky. I belive if you'd try to pass / return struct by value, for example, or struct with gaps between the memebers, then you'll see the difference. After all, ARM is 32-bits and most probably you're compiling for x86-64 :)